# How to parent a grease pencil with armature?

Tags: armature, parent, grease-pencil

How to parent a grease pencil stroke with armature for a 2d animation. Please try to post a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a drop down menu below the layer.choose armature and then choose bone..there should be a list of bones. (it does not matter if the gp layer is attached to an object or the scene.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm talking Blender 2.8 here...

- Select your 2D drawing object
- Shift select your armature
- Press CTRL + P to open parenting menu
- Select parent mode of your liking (I normally choose automatic weights and adjust afterwards)
- Adjust weights in options of your drawing